# How to install dependencies in Angular 7 from scratch?

Tags: angular, dependencies, angular7

I have installed the last version Angular using CLI. There is package.json in root directory. I run command: `npm install`. It installed dependencies.

When I tried to use package in application, in `pipe` or `component` like:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

It can not find this dependency. How to use and install npm packages in new Angular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right way to install dependencies is to use **package json**.

Therefore need to add package to this file in `"dependencies": {}` section.

Then run `npm install` in root directory where is placed this file. After Angular aware about all dependencies and you can import them in components, pipes .etc.

Answer (score 2):

The installation is the same as usual

```
npm i --save lodash
```

Visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash

Read this [article](https://medium.com/@armno/til-importing-lodash-into-angular-the-better-way-aacbeaa40473) talks about how to use lodash with angular.

Comment: Does it mean install globally?

Comment: Now I have lodash in `node_modules`, but it is not imported to component

Comment: I update the answer linking an article talking about how to use the library with angular. Hope it helps